# Drop rows in R based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am new to R and stack overflow so please bear with me as I am trying my best to describe my problem here. I would like to drop certain rows of the data frame if certain conditions are met.  To access the data frame:

```
Time <- c(5.58, 12.79, 14.27, 14.35, 18.18, 19.62, 20.69, 20.70, 20.80, 22.65)
Signal <- c(532.0603, 290.8152, 390.9111, 778.8482, 541.6486, 855.9310, 445.0463, 887.9447, 889.1131, 490.0643)
data.frame(Time, Signal)
```

```
  Time   Signal
  5.58 532.0603
 12.79 290.8152
 14.27 390.9111
 14.35 778.8482
 18.18 541.6486
 19.62 855.9310
 20.69 445.0463
 20.70 887.9447
 20.80 889.1131
 22.65 490.0643
```

The first thing I would like to do is **if** Time A is within 0.2 of Time B **and**  Signal B is no greater than 2 of Signal A, then drop Row B. So my expected outcome will be

```
  Time   Signal
  5.58 532.0603
 12.79 290.8152
 14.27 390.9111
 14.35 778.8482
 18.18 541.6486
 19.62 855.9310
 20.69 445.0463
 20.70 887.9447
 22.65 490.0643
```

The second thing is if Time A is within 0.2 of Time B **and** abs((Signal B + 2)/2 - Signal A) < 1, then drop Row A. And my expected outcome is:

```
  Time   Signal
  5.58 532.0603
 12.79 290.8152
 14.35 778.8482
 18.18 541.6486
 19.62 855.9310
 20.70 887.9447
 22.65 490.0643
```

My thought is that I may have to write a function with a while loop but was not sure if that is the right way or how to execute. I have actually spent many hours trying to figure out this and I would appreciate very much for your help if you could help me on this, thank you so much!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Row "A" is the first row, right?

Comment: Yes @Edward, Row A is first row and Row B is the next Row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:

We can use `Lead` and `Lag` function which can refer to next or previous rows respectively.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(Timediff = Time - lag(Time), SignalDiff = Signal - lag(Signal)) %>%
  filter(Timediff >0.2 | SignalDiff >=2| is.na(Timediff)) %>% 
  mutate(Timediff = lead(Time) - Time, SignalDiff = lead(Signal)-Signal) %>%
  filter(Timediff >0.2 |  abs((lead(Signal) + 2)/2 - Signal) >1|is.na(SignalDiff)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(Time, Signal)

   Time   Signal
1  5.58 532.0603
2 12.79 290.8152
3 14.35 778.8482
4 18.18 541.6486
5 19.62 855.9310
6 20.70 887.9447
7 22.65 490.0643
```

Comment: Thanks very much Harshal for your help! Lead and Lag are really excellent tools here. Simple but powerful. Really appreciate!

Comment: @Ben Can you tell us what changes you made? is there anything i had missed? thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope - all fine. Just added newline after each pipe for readability, that's all.